# how to get the underlying buffer of EGLImage?

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I want to implement OMX_UseEGLImage in my native openmax componet on android,but how to get the underlying buffer associated with an EGLImage specified by eglImage?

the client api will create a EGLImage and call OMX_UseEGLImage to notify my native openmax componet to use eglimage:

```
eglImage = eglCreateImageKHR(
      m_egl_display,
      m_egl_context,
      EGL_GL_TEXTURE_2D_KHR,
      (EGLClientBuffer)(egl_buffer->texture_id),
      &attrib);

OMX_UseEGLImage(hComponent,ppBufferHdr,nPortIndex,pAppPrivate,eglImage);
```

the problem is how i can use eglImage? is there anyway get the underlying buffer associated with  eglImage?

Comment: this problem have troubled me for several days,could somebody give me some advice? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the call `OMX_UseEGLImage` is only applicable to render.

For example, consider the two components: decoder and render with tunneled communication. Decoder output port connected to the Render input port via tunnel. Decoder output port is buffer supplier.

At the transition from OMX_StateLoaded to OMX_StateIdle:

1. Decoder creates native buffer:
   `android::GraphicBuffer * buffer = new android::GraphicBuffer();
   android_native_buffer_t * native_buffer = buffer->getNativeBuffer();`
2. Decoder creates EGLImage:
   `EGLImageKHR egl_image = eglCreateImageKHR((EGLClientBuffer)native_buffer)`
3. Decoder call on tunneled port:
    `OMX_UseEGLImage(&buffer_header, egl_image)`
4. Render allocates a buffer_header and remembers egl_image

In the state OMX_StateIdle:

1. The decoder knows the correspondence between the native buffer, buffer_header and egl_image.
2. The render knows the correspondence between the buffer_header and egl_image.

In the state OMX_StateExecuting:

1. Decoder writes frames in native buffer, and call `OMX_EmptyThisBuffer(buffer_header)` on the tunneled port
2. Render call `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(egl_image)` to draw frames.

At the transition from OMX_StateIdle to OMX_StateLoaded:

1. Decoder call `OMX_FreeBuffer(buffer_header)` on tunneled port
2. Render free buffer_header
3. Decoder call `eglDestroyImageKHR(egl_image)`
4. Decoder delete native_buffer